# Ethernet says it's connected but can't access the internet

Tags: ethernet

I downloaded Ubuntu yesterday and tried to hook up to the internet.

In the top right it shows ethernet connection, but yet I'm not able to use the internet.

I found out how to get photos but it says I need at least ten reputation to post images.

Comment: Can you ping URLs (`ping google.com`), internet IPs (`ping 8.8.8.8`), local IPs, e.g. of your router (`ping 192.168.0.1`, replace IP with your own router's one)?

Comment: can you paste the result of the following commands: `sudo ifconfig` and `route`. And consider that it may also be an issue with your router, can you restart it?

Comment: Typing this from my phone so I  can't paste. Have restarted my router multiple times

Comment: I am able to ping my own router yet when I going websites it says unknown host

Comment: Are you using names (e.g. `http://www.google.com`) or IP addresses? Does [this link](http://62.1.38.148) work? I'm afraid we can't help you if you don't show the output of those commands since we need more information. If you  must, take a screenshot and post that.

Comment: I'm pinging names (http://www.Google.com) and it says unknown host, I know my router and ethernet cable works because I can hook it up to my old computer and get instant internet. I'm trying to find a way to post the results of those commands but with no success so far. So far it says I'm connected, I have a ipv4 address, I can ling my router, I can ping myself,

Comment: Tried to ping myself again.      Ping -c4 8.8.4.4        and it says network is unreachable

Comment: `8.8.4.4` is not you, not unless you're google :) Did you try the link I gave in my previous comment? It sounds like you are connected but haven't set up your [DNS](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/dns_domainnamesystem/f/dns_servers.htm) correctly. Please [edit] your question and tell us i) if you can connect to google using this: http://62.1.38.148/ ; ii) mention that you have an ipv4 address; iii) run the commands, take a photo with your phone and post that.

Answer (score 0):

Although more details about network status would have been better, but anyway you can try running the following command in terminal

sudo service network-manager restart

This command restarts the network manager service which generally solves the connection problem.

Comment: Sorry about the details kinda new to this

Comment: I can ping my own router, but can't ling websites. Have tried restarting network manager but nothing happend

Comment: Tried the command  and got back.   Network-manager unrecognized service

Comment: Please include all the things you've tried and the details (like that you have and IP address) in your post. Comments can be deleted without warning and are easy to miss anyway.